# MS Access SQL Date Calculation with Single Date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables linked to a MS Access database I have created. One of my tables contains many rows of data and has one field with a date in there. My second table has one single field and one single entry, which is the date.

My second table at the moment has a field called "ReportDate" and then the content is "2019-03-04".

I am trying to create a query to perform the difference between the dates in the first table and the single date in the second table.

Table 1

```
ID  Location    Date
1   US  2019-05-10
2   US  2019-06-15
3   CA  2019-05-23
4   CA  2019-06-04
5   US  2019-10-20
```

Table 2

```
ReportDate
2019-03-05
```

RESULT

```
ID  Location    Date    DayDiff
1   US  2019-05-10  66
2   US  2019-06-15  102
3   CA  2019-05-23  79
4   CA  2019-06-04  91
5   US  2019-10-20  229
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I tried DateDiff("d",Table2.ReportDate,Table1.Date), but realized that I have nothing joining the 2 tables together. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `cross join`, which in MS Access is done with a comma:

```
select t1.*, t2.ReportDate,
       DateDiff("d", t2.ReportDate, t1.Date)
from table1 as t1,
     table2 as t2
```

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to mention I am doing a LEFT JOIN already. Would this change your answer? I am LEFT JOINING with another table to bring in some data. I can also alternatively just run a separate query off the resulting LEFT JOIN. How would I incorporate the cross join with an existing LEFT JOIN? Thanks for the very quick reply!

Comment: @MonkeyMonkey . . . This answers the question that you have asked.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.  This question is explicitly about two tables and has no other `JOIN` operations.

Comment: Thanks Gordon Linoff. I was able to get your solution to work.